# React when URL could not be Routed in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There are a number of known exploits out there that probe for URLs like

> /mysqladmin/index.php
>
> /db/index.php
>
> /xampp/phpmyadmin/index.php

When we come across these in my server logs, we grab the IP and add to the firewall black list.

I would like to detect these (from a known list) in my MVC 4 application so that I can proactively alert the ops team of an IP address that is launching exploits.

Is there a good hook into MVC 4 to catch URL requests that could not be routed to a controller and take further action?

Comment: I hope your 'ops team' has a lot of free time on their hands... I get thousands of these a day. Almost all are automated, and aren't even worth an IP ban, since many of them likely are zombie PCs, meaning next week that IP could be a legitimate user. IMHO. YMMV. BYOB.

Comment: They may decide not to blacklist the IP if the volume is too large, but they can still see if there is a new URL being requested to see if there's a new vulnerability to be aware of.  All legitimate users of the website are from Fortune 1000 companies that are unlikely to be running zombie PCs.

Answer (score 0):

A simply way is having a wildcard routing route below all the other rules.

```
routes.MapRoute
(
   "Error", 
   "{*url}", 
   new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
);
```

Comment: Erm... would not this route break links for static content?